# Agregar iconos a la Actionbar

Tags: android, actionbar

Estoy buscando lo siguiente: poner el icono y al lado el titulo, como se muestra en la imagen donde esta el icono de **Google Photos** y al lado dice **Fotos**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/admin"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_email_white_24dp"
        android:title="Enviar Comentario"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/acerca"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Acerca de"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/salir"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Salir"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

esto que tengo cuando lo abro sólo se muestra el texto y no el icono más el texto. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba a poner el menú de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="es.uv.lisitt.actionbartest.MainActivity">
>

   <item
       android:id="@+id/empty"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:orderInCategory="101"
       app:showAsAction="always">
       <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/admin"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:title="Enviar Comentario"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/acerca"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="Acerca de"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/salir"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="Salir"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

en el que tu lista de elementos será un submenú en el que fuerza que se muestren siempre junto con el texto con estas propiedades: `showAsAction="always|withText"`

**Editado:**

He modificado el código anterior y lo he probado en un proyecto de prueba y funciona correctamente.

Lo he probado con la siguiente configuración de gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.prueba.actionbartest"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Saliendo el menú de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no resulta, muestra solo el icono y en la action bar, no como aparece en la foto ...

Comment: @FelixBeeb seguiré investigando mañana cuando llegue a casa, que hasta mañana no tendré un pc a mano

Comment: Gracias, yo igual he investigado el tema, pero tal vez el problema radica en que yo uso un ActionBar y tal vez esta propiedad funciona en una Toolbar

Comment: @FelixBeeb yo creo que con ActionBar también se podía pero no recuerdo como

Comment: La verdad desconozco eso

Comment: @FelixBeeb he hecho unas pruebas y he conseguido hacer lo que pides, he modificado mi código, si necesitas algo más no dudes en pedirmelo

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo y el trabajo !

Comment: De nada @FelixBeeb! Espero te haya servido de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias @joacer. Con tu ejemplo logré que se vieran los íconos antes del texto en el submenú, antes solo lo lograba sobre la toolbar/appbar.
Saludos

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
       android:id="@+id/empty"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
       android:orderInCategory="101"
       android:showAsAction="always">
       <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/admin"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_email_white_24dp"
                android:title="Enviar Comentario"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/acerca"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="Acerca de"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/salir"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="Salir"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: la propiedad IfRoom mostrara los iconos si tiene espacio en la actionbar pero yo necesito que se muestre siempre en el sub menu es decir al hacer click en esos 3 puntitos ...

Comment: pense que para ponerlo en los 3 puntitos solo debes agrupar los item en las etiquetas <menu>...</menu>

Comment: Así es, pero una vez dentro necesito que se muestre el icono mas el texto como en la imagen

Comment: intenta "ifRoom|withText"